# Set a custom application Icon for a Class Library deployed using ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, class-library

I have a C# project in VS2012 with an output type set to "Class Library", in fact it is a VSTO word 2010 add-in, after publishing the project and installing it with ClickOnce, I notices that the icon used in the "Programs and Features" list is the default icon, which is not really professional IMO. I would like to be able to set a custom icon for my application but as its a Class Library I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to do it.

In the "Application" tab of my project properties in the "Resources" section, the "Icon and Manifest" option is selected by default but it is disabled so I can't select and Icon file. I fear there is no way to do it for a class library project, but I haven't found any confirmation of this either.

Thanks for any informatin/help you might give.

Comment: All I found for now is this thread on [Social.MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cd3619c-0e66-4eef-be91-0dcd3b108235/vsto-clickonce-application-icon?forum=vsto) that says it cannot be done for VSTO add-in projects. Its from 2011, I would've thought they solved this already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a couple hours I think this is not possible right now, see [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cd3619c-0e66-4eef-be91-0dcd3b108235/vsto-clickonce-application-icon?forum=vsto) that I posted in a comment on the OP above. Its a bit sad as it would look a lot more profesional if we could put a custom application icon on a vsto addin that would be visible in the Programs and Feature list in the control panel...